# Search in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex

I have a json array:

```
var arr = 
 [
  {
    "path": "a/b/c/*",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "path": "l/m/*/n",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "path": "a/b/c/d/*",
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

I want the id of the element which matches the input param,
like if I pass a input string and the array I should get the id

```
foo(input,arr);
```

so

```
var input = 'a/b/c/5'; //or input = 'a/b/c/4';
foo(input,arr) // should return 1
```

similarly

```
var input = 'l/m/78/n';
foo(input,arr); // should return 2
```

similarly

```
var input = 'a/b/c/d/1';
foo(input,arr); // should return 3
```

So I want * to be the wildcard while search.
I have struggled a lot while implementing this, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert each `path` into a [**regular expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), noting that the regular expression for a wildcard is `.*` instead of `*`.

Based on your updated question, and assuming the wildcard should match numbers only, the regular expression becomes `[0-9]+`:

```js
var arr =  [{"path": "a/b/c/*","id": "1"},
            {"path": "l/m/*/n","id": "2"},
            {"path": "a/b/c/d/*","id": "3"}
           ];

function foo(input, arr) {
  var i, RE;
  
  for(i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) { //iterate through the array
    RE = new RegExp(arr[i].path.replace(/\*/g, '[0-9]+')); //convert path to regexp
    if(RE.test(input)) { //test for a match
      return arr[i].id;
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo('a/b/c/5', arr));
console.log(foo('l/m/78/n', arr));
console.log(foo('a/b/c/d/1', arr));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was such a help.

Comment: I have missed one scenario and just made an update to the question, the solution will fail if I pass a/b/c/d/1, its returning id=1, but should give id=3

Comment: Can you please update the answer, I will be highly indebtful

Comment: Sure, done.  My update assumes the wildcard is used only for numbers.  Let me know if that's not the case.

Comment: Yeah, thats quite helpful, actually I added another check in your solution, I compare number of slashes on both sides, if equal I do RE.test(inut)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function foo(input,arr){

for(var i in arr){
  var re = new RegExp(arr[i].path.replace(/\*/g, '.*'));
  if (re.test(input)) {
  return arr[i].id;
  }
}

return null;

}

var arr = 
 [
  {
    "path": "a/b/c/*",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "path": "l/m/*/n",
    "id": "2"
  }
];


document.write(foo("l/m/1/n",arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex free version:

```js
var arr = [{
 'path' : 'a/b/c/*',
 'id' : '1'
}, {
 'path' : 'l/m/*/n',
 'id' : '2'
}
]
function search(arr, input) {
input = input.split('/');
return arr.filter(function (el) {
 var value = el.path.replace('*', '').split('/');
 var passed = true;
 for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
  if (input[i].length < 1 || value[i].length < 1 || input[i] == value[i]) {}
  else {
   passed = false;
  }
 }
 return passed;
})
}
console.log(search(arr, 'a/b/c/5'));
console.log(search(arr, 'l/m/78/n'));
```